# "SHA256" sum is not sha256

Tags: sha, tizen

I have replaced an image inside of a TPK file (Tizen Install package) but it will not install.

Inside the TPK file, there are two signature files signature1.xml, and author-signature.xml.

In both of them, they have this:

```
<Reference URI="shared/res/ACL-splash.png">
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod>
<DigestValue>wgvWtVSJns8mCgUPfBZ/2ZTBfKqR02zW0MD4tA3cIBE=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
```

It links to information about sha256 values, but when I find the sha256 value for my edited file I get this:

**Sha1**: 53f3002da277c92d86e1c356ded39ce3dd91512b

**Sha256**: 463e0102f54ee7370b84f5b1570ac0d77791244d5b2b06f023e0e4831a23bfe4

Neither of them are the right length

In addition, the original file has a different sha than what is listed:

**Sha1**: 4c3e051a5ef68c63a45b38abaa63e1038d318bc3

**sha256**: c20bd6b554899ecf260a050f7c167fd994c17caa91d36cd6d0c0f8b40ddc2011

When you install the modified files on a tizen phone, it says:

```
__return_cb req_id[29370002] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[VZtRZw5cZM] key[error] val[79] error message: Invalid signature. Signed with wrong key, changed signature file or changed package file
__return_cb req_id[29370002] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[VZtRZw5cZM] key[end] val[fail]
processing result : SIGNATURE_INVALID_HASH_SIGNATURE [79] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [6309]ms
```

(ignore the pkgid part)

But when you add an equal sign to the end of the hash that you put in, it says:

```
__return_cb req_id[29870002] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[VZtRZw5cZM] key[error] val[32]
__return_cb req_id[29870002] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[VZtRZw5cZM] key[end] val[fail]
processing result : CERTIFICATE_INVALID [32] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [6251]ms
```

Answer (score 1):

To resign the tizen package (`.tpk`), you need to use tizen cli.

Re-sign the package.

Windows:

```
tizen package -t tpk -s MyProfile -- C:\Users\workspace\basic\Debug\org.tizen.basic-1.0.0-i386.tpk
Author certificate: C:\tizen-sdk-data\keystore\author\mycert.p12
Distributor1 certificate : C:\tizen-sdk\tools\certificate-generator\certificates\distributor\tizen-distributor-signer.p12
Package (C:\Users\workspace\basic\Debug\org.tizen.basic-1.0.0-i386.tpk) is created successfully.
```

Ubuntu and macOS:

```
$ tizen package -t tpk -s MyProfile -- ~/workspace/basic/Debug/org.tizen.basic-1.0.0-i386.tpk
Author certificate: ~/tizen-sdk-data/keystore/author/mycert.p12
Distributor1 certificate : ~/tizen-sdk/tools/certificate-generator/certificates/distributor/tizen-distributor-signer.p12
Package (~/workspace/basic/Debug/org.tizen.basic-1.0.0-i386.tpk) is created successfully.
```

For more detail, you can refer to below tizen cli guide.

https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/native-tools/cli

Answer (score 0):

Your sample values are in hex, whereas the XML contains base64.

For example, your SHA-256 value is 64 hex digits, so 32 bytes - which makes sense for SHA-256, which is 256 bits.

The `DigestValue` in the XML is 44 characters including one padding character - which is what I'd expect for 32 bytes, where every 3 bytes require 4 characters.

For example, here's some C# code to take the base64 hash and convert it to (dash-separated) hex:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte[] hash = Convert.FromBase64String("wgvWtVSJns8mCgUPfBZ/2ZTBfKqR02zW0MD4tA3cIBE=");
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hash));        
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
C2-0B-D6-B5-54-89-9E-CF-26-0A-05-0F-7C-16-7F-D9-94-C1-7C-AA-91-D3-6C-D6-D0-C0-F8-B4-0D-DC-20-11
```

... which matches the hash you computed for the original file, so at least you know you're computing it the right way.

I don't know anything about Tizen itself, but it sounds like you may need to update that XML file to include the base64 of the SHA-256 hash... or if you delete it, does the tooling replace it for you?

Comment: How would I convert the hash to base64? If I delete it completely, it just gives the signed with wrong key error message

Comment: @Qiangong2: We don't know what code you're using to compute the hash, but if you're using C# you'd just use `Convert.ToBase64(hashAsByteArray)`.